# Alinear Auto Flow Grid Desde la Derecha

Tags: css, css3, grid

tengo el siguiente codigo.

```css
.container{
    margin:auto;
    width: min(100%, 800px);
    border: 1px solid #0e0e0e;
    min-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: start;
    justify-items: center;
}
.container a{
    border: 1px solid #0e0e0e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como ven el autoflow de las columnas parte de izquierda a derecha, como puedo lograr que aparezcan de manera inversa?, es decir, de derecha a izquierda cuando la pantalla va reduciendo de tamaño.

Comment: Prueba con `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` o `direction: rtl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad [**`direction: rtl`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/direction) en donde significa que la dirección de los elementos serán de derecha a izquierda (**r**ight **t**o **l**eft), ejemplo:

```css
.container{
    margin:auto;
    width: min(100%, 800px);
    border: 1px solid #0e0e0e;
    min-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: start;
    justify-items: center;
    direction: rtl;
}
.container a{
    border: 1px solid #0e0e0e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Crack! Excelente, no me la sabia.

Comment: De nada, te invito a que verifiques la respuesta si te sirvió, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/direction) para definir el sentido de la lectura.

```css
.container{
    margin:auto;
    width: min(100%, 800px);
    border: 1px solid #0e0e0e;
    min-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: start;
    justify-items: center;
    direction: rtl;
}
.container a{
    border: 1px solid #0e0e0e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        <a href="#">Link 7</a>
        <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me percaté que habías dado otra respuesta... y luego copiaste a la mía... en la cual, la anterior respuesta tuya estaba bien. Sería bueno si dejaras como estaba, de esta forma serían 2 respuestas **distintas**, tal como estaba antes...

Comment: Amigo excelente respuesta, muchas gracias por la información, al igual que el compañero de arriba, ambos estan en lo correcto.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev es que probando mi código me di cuenta que no hacían falta dos propiedades que tenía, por eso lo modifiqué